# How can I put Apache Spark Into Snapcraft

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, snapcraft

Currently trying to get Apache Spark working through Snapcraft, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the .yaml:

```
name: spark
version: 1.0
architectures:
 - amd64
summary: The Spark Engine 
description: This is the Spark Engine produced by snapcraft with maven.
confinement: strict

apps:
 spark:
   command: bin/wrapper
   daemon: simple
   plugs: [network-bind]

parts:
    webapp:
        plugin: maven
        source: https://github.com/lool/snappy-mvn-demo.git
        source-type: git
    spark:
        plugin: tar-content
        source: http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-1.6.2/spark-1.6.2.tgz
        local-files:
        plugin: make
        source: .
```

Here is the make file:

```
all:

install:
    cp -a spark-conf/ $(DESTDIR)/
```

The make file doessnt contain a wrapper because I cant find one.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Where does `local-files` come from? Dropping it lets the build pass, but then I run into http://paste.ubuntu.com/20450695/

Comment: the local-files are the Spark Conf file, figured I need it

Comment: But `local-files` is not defined in the world of `snapcraft`.

Answer (score 0):

The `local-files:` looks like it needs to be indented 1 less to fit the yaml format. Also, you may need to specify that the local-files part is run after the others by add the `after` key

```
    local-files:
        plugin: make
        source: .
        after: [webapp,spark]
```